# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class$$anonfun$1 after calling map transformation on rdd in yarn-client mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, rdd

I am running following spark 1.6.0 application in eclipse

```
object LoanDataRDD {
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
val sConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Loan Data Analysis DD").setMaster("yarn-client");
val sc = new SparkContext(sConf);    
val rawData = sc.textFile("TranAnalytics/week1/resources/loan.csv").map(rec=>if(!(rec.contains("addr_state")))(rec.split(",")(23),rec));    
rawData.take(5).foreach (println)      
 }
}//runs fine in local mode.
```

it runs fine without map function but after adding

```
".map(rec=>if(!(rec.contains("addr_state")))(rec.split(",")(23),rec))"
```

it is throwing following exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.df.LoanData$$anonfun$1
```

But It runs successfully after setting

```
sConf.set("spark.jars",   "/home/cloudera/Tran_analytics/week1/dependency/class_jar/*")// path to jar 
file of LoanDataRDD itself.
```

So would anybody help me to understand this behavior? why it is not able to find 
    spark.df.LoanData$$anonfun$1 ,its function and have to add jar file of 
     itself while running in **yarn-clien**t mode?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: As I mentioned in question ,It ran successfully after adding the jar file of itself but still could not understand the behavior.